# Photoshop Drag Deselect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

Is there an easy way to drag deselect layers using auto-select?

I often use drag select to select layers, but often this ends up select other layers that happen to partially overlap. I'd like to be able to drag over these extra layers and deselect them.

Thanks,

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I'm not really understand your case is. But for me personally yes `auto-select` was a risk feature for me and I always switch it off. And better using `right-click` and select the layer. Sorry if that's not the concern

Comment: not sure if this is answer for your question, but if you have auto-select on, then with holding ctrl you will turn it off, and you can move your selected layer.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to do that, at least i have never seen it. But there are two other ways, i wish this capability was there but it's not.

Other ways:

1. Use drag selection to select all elements then hold **Ctrl** and
   click on the ones you want to deselect.
2. Or Hold **shitf+ctrl** and right click and select the layer you want
   to be deselected.